# Is there a proof concerning the Collatz Conjecture that all odd numbers (n) divisible by 3 eventually encounter a number divisible by 8?

Tags: proof-writing, collatz-conjecture

I'm vaguely aware that people have proved that by starting with any number, and iterating through the Collatz algorithm one will eventually reach a number divisible by 4.

But I am looking for the proof that one will eventually reach a number divisible by 8 for every odd number n divisible by 3. This seems to be the case, for example 3→16, 9→40, etc. but I'm looking for a proof of it.

Is it logically known that this is the case? How might one go about proving that?

Comment: What about $27$? That gets mapped to $82$, which gets mapped to $41$, and $41$ is neither a multiple of $3$ _or_ a multiple of $8$!

Comment: @H.sapiensrex The question is whether or not one will *eventually* reach a number divisible by $8.$ The sequence starting at $27$ contains $7288$ which is divisible by $8.$ So that is not a counter-example.

Comment: Oh, my bad lol. Didn't process the question properly; thought OP's conjecture was about the immediate next number in the sequence lol

Comment: $+1$, interesting question. I looked at $a_1\equiv 1\pmod 8,\ a_1\equiv 3\pmod 8,\ a_1\equiv 5\pmod 8,\ a_1\equiv 7\pmod 8,\ $ and other than $\ a_1\equiv 5 \pmod 8 \to 16\pmod 8 \equiv 0 \pmod 8,\ $ I didn't get very far. My intuition tells me this is just as hard as the Collatz conjecture itself but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: There must be a number divisible by 4 unless the Collatz conjecture is false, otherwise the numbers would keep growing. *3+1, /2, ^3+1, /2 etc. _Maybe_ there is a similar argument.

Comment: @gnasher729, the proof that we always reach a number divisible by 4 does not require the Collatz conjecture to be true

Comment: @Collag3n You’d have to prove that there is no sequence growing infinitely.

Comment: @gnasher729, no, you have to prove that no sequence can go to infinity with no division by 4, which is easy to prove

Comment: for an odd number $n$ you have a division by 4 after exactly $\nu_2(n+1)$ steps of the condensed Collatz function ($\frac{3x+1}{2}$), so a finite number of steps. And if $n$ is even, you have either 1 additional step or already a division by 4

Comment: @Collag3n yes divisibility by 4 is guaranteed and obvious, 8  is always observed, seems obviously required as well, and by an extension of the same reason, but I can't formalize it. I have learned, since I asked this question though that it doesn't help with the line of reasoning I was going down so I'm not as concerned about answering this question as I was.

Comment: If you are able to count the number of trailing zeros when $x$ is represented in base 2, then you check if this number is $log_2(8)$. Maybe one can make a general form for this and check any pow 2 number.

Comment: Can you please specify in the question whether your function for odd numbers goes $3x+1$ or to $(3x+1)/2$

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby the collatz conjecture is called "3n+1" but of course the /2 is implied, since you always have to divide by 2 at least once to get to an odd number. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @MetaStack if you go $(3n+1)/2$ then $\frac73$ never gets to a multiple of $8$ but if you use $3n+1$ it does.

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby in the collatz conjecture only whole numbers are used. if you have an even whole number you divide it by 2 if you have an odd whole number you multiply it by 3 and add 1 (which gives you an even number, thus the division by 2 is implied). Indeed, it's functionally equivalent to (3n+.5)/2 when used on numbers that are not whole numbers (which will always only be a whole number and a half if you start with a whole number). And since it works on whole numbers exclusively I've often thought that an "all-primes" base p-adic number could provide insight, but alas.

Comment: @MetaStack do you now understand my question whether you are using $(3x+1)/2$ or $3x+1$ sufficiently to answer it?  If not, think a bit more about my comment.

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby guess not, feel free to provide more clarification. I'm not that smart, I don't think more of my cycles will provide insight, as I thought I understood your misunderstanding already.

Comment: ok lets go in baby steps. can you see that this statement is true, and why: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712669/is-there-a-proof-concerning-the-collatz-conjecture-that-all-odd-numbers-n-divi?noredirect=1#comment10017405_4712669

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby yes, I can see it's true and why. Perhaps I should answer it more clearly: 3n+1, not (3n+1)/2. Edit: actually I still think it's irrelevant question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bijective function for all numbers of the form $8n+5: f(n−1)\frac{1}{4}$. However, this is nonobvious except for $5→1$. Let me explain.

One can state that for every even-odd sequence $n$, sequence $4n+1$ has two extra steps.
For example: **27** - 111 steps, **109** - 113 steps, **437** - 115 steps, **1749** - 117 steps, **6997** - 119 steps, **27989** - 121 steps, … $\infty$

This follows from the salient fact that each time you multiply $4n+1$ by $3n+1$ – that is, $(((n*4)+1)3)+1$ – you add two factors of $2$.

This is not immediately obvious in even-odd sequences since, given that for any such orbit (if I may call it that), the first $n$ is absent from the next sequence.
Thus, for example, sequence $501$ does not have the step $125$, and sequence $125$ does not have the step $31$.

**501** → 1504 →752 → 376 → 188 → 94 → **47**

**125** → 376 → 188 → 94 → **47**

**31** → 94 → **47**

---

The apparent difficulty of the conjecture, therefore, lies in the odd numbers, such as $27$, that are not multiples of $4$ plus $1$. That’s three out of four odd sequence numbers, of course. However, we see there are two other operations – injective functions – that knit all these sequence $n$s together, too. These are:

For every $4n+3$, $f(n+1)\frac{3}{2}-1$. For example: 27→41, 31→47.

For every $8n+1$, $f(n−1)\frac{3}{4}+1$. For example: 41→31, 49→37.

Answer (score 0):

If the Collatz conjecture (every sequence ends in 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1) is true, then starting with any odd number n >= 3 encounters a number divisible by 8.

Proof: Let n be a number that doesn't encounter a multiple of 8. Starting with n, and assuming the Collatz conjecture is true, we eventually encounter the number 1, and this happens after an operation x -> 3x + 1 gives a power 2^k, which is k times divided by 2. We assumed that 3x + 1 is not divisible by 8, so k = 1 or k = 2, and 3x + 1 = 2 or 3x + 1 = 4. This implies x = 1. So this only happens if we started the sequence with x = 1.

The same argument shows there is also an element divisible by 16 because 3x + 1 = 8 is not possible, but not necessarily one divisible by 32 since 3x + 1 = 16 is possible (starting with x = 3 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 1)

PS. I'd be curious if the same can be proven without assuming the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: What you are curious about is precisely the question that was asked

Comment: If you're going to assume the Collatz conjecture is true then why not simply say that every odd multiple of $3$ eventually reaches $16$ and then $8$. (Indeed, every sequence would either start within or reach $16,8,4,2,1,4,2,1,\dots$)